# Google Web Toolkit throws java.security.AccessControlException

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, accesscontrolexception

I'm trying to read a sqlite db from the server side code in my gwt project. It throws AccessControlException. I looked a lot on the web and all solutions seems to be disabling Google App Engine, but when I do this, I can't run my project. I'm new to GWT and I have no idea where it runs when Google App Engine is shut down. I look for possibly this two solutions: Any setting that Google App Engine is set to be able to read any file, or other engine that I run my application on. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Google App Engine (GAE) does not support sqlite (I assume you are reading it using JDBC).

If your intention is to make a GWT project that will not be deployed on GAE, you should create the project disabling this feature from the very beginning, because afterwards its a nightmare as you are experiencing right now.

If your intention is to deploy in GAE, you must use the google's persistence mechanisms (JDO) to store your data.  SqlLite is off the table here.

Comment: I downloaded SQLite Driver JDBC, add classpath to the project and web-inf as well, No problem loading jdbc class,so why not support if all required libraries added? The problem is the GAE can't read/write files in location

Comment: Because GAE is limited in its persistence model, no mater the drivers that you install in your project.  As you noted, you can download the drivers locally, but if GAE is enabled it will no work.